# Duplicate string detection in C

Tags: c, function

I'm trying to create a function that removes duplicate strings from a stream in C. The strings are already sorted so the only necessary step is to check the string that just appeared to make sure the current string is not a duplicate. However, my attempted implementation is not giving me the correct output.In fact, I get no output at all. The strings are separated by newline characters. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

```
void dupEliminate(int file, char string[100])
    {

  FILE *stream;
  stream = fdopen(file, "r");
  char* savedString;
  char* prevString;
  while(!feof(stream)){
    (fgets(savedString, 100, stream));
    if(strcmp(savedString,prevString) != 0 ){
        strcat(string, savedString);
        strcpy(prevString,savedString);
  }
```

Comment: What role is `string` supposed to play in this function?

Comment: You appear to be overwriting `string` every time to no end??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 char* prevString;
```

`prevString` is uninitialized in this function , and yet you compare it here -

```
 if(strcmp(savedString,prevString) != 0 )
```

Also , before taking input in `savedString` using `fgets` , ***you need to allocate memory to it using*** `malloc` or `calloc` ,as it is an unintialized pointer.

What it will compare to ? Initialize you `prevString` and then compare it .

**Note**- Just a suggestion instead of using `while(!feof(stream))`  , use `fgets` to control loop -

```
while(fgets(savedString, 100, stream)!=NULL){
...
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, I always forget to malloc in C and that termination condition works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @raze18 You are welcome , and also remember to `free` allocated memory :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give savedString and prevString some memory - malloc or make them char[101]

You will also need to initialise prevString

prevString needs to be updated with the last line unconditionally, not in the `if` block

I don't like the names either :)

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you ultimately want to do with the non-duplicate strings given the code you have posted. At present, even if you collect only non-duplicate strings, you are currently overwriting the value in `string` without doing any thing with it.

If you are reading from a continual stream, then you either need to just print (or save or copy) the non-duplicate `string` somewhere to make use of it, or you need to buffer the non-duplicate strings somewhere and make use of them when your buffer is full.

Since you say you are not getting the correct output, but have no output functions listed, it is somewhat of a guess what you are trying to do. If you simply want to output the non-duplicate strings, then you can simply print them (note using `fgets` you will have a `newline` at the end of each string read). An example would be:

```
#define MAXC 100
...
    char string[MAXC] = {0};
...

void dupEliminate (int file, char *string)
{
    FILE *stream;
    stream = fdopen (file, "r");
    if (!stream) {
        fprintf (stderr, "dupEliminate() error: stream open failed.\n");
        return;
    }
    char pre[MAXC] = {0};   /* previous string  */
    size_t word = 0;

    while (fgets (string, MAXC, stream)) {

        if (word == 1) {
            if (strcmp (pre, string) != 0) {
                printf ("%s", pre);
                printf ("%s", string);
            }
            else
                printf ("%s", string);
        }

        if (word > 1 && strcmp (pre, string) != 0)
            printf ("%s", string);

        strncpy (pre, string, MAXC);
        word++;
    }
    fclose (stream);
}
```

If your intent was to buffer all non-duplicate strings and make them available in `main()`, then there are several things you need to do. Let me know if you have any further questions and I'm happy to work with your further once I have more details about your intent.